# What is an authentication bootstrapper

Tags: npm, npm-install

What is an "authentication bootstrapper" used in the context of the [vsts-npm-auth library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsts-npm-auth)? The term bootstrap seems to be undefined but highly used. For example, Microsoft has created an API called [bootstrap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/bootstrapper/bootstrap). I have my own definition (an automated process used to configure an SKE or other software application) but I don't know an authoritative source for bootstrap or bootstrapper.